# How to access to an instance of another class which has constructor of another class

Tags: java, constructor

I have a class A with setters and getters.
I have a class B where I call a constructor from A and set some variables.
I have a class C where I want to call variables set up in class B.
How can i call that in class C?

```
public class A{
private String name;
private String status;
private int id;

public A(String status, String name) {
    this.status = status;
    this.name = name;
}
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}}



public class B{

A a;

public void add() {
    a= new A("Test", "Test");
}

public void add_to() {
        int id = Math.abs(new Random().nextInt());

        a.setId(id);
}


public class C{

public void add() {
    //How can I call variable id declared in class B???
   }
}
```

Instead of just adding more methods in the class B I would like to continue to use the same constructor with stored variables that I have created in class B already.

Comment: You don't. You haven't "created" anything yet, you've only "defined" things: since B has no static fields, there is nothing _to_ access, because nothing exists. Also, if all B does is wrap an A, why not make B an extension of A instead? That way you can just call `getId()` on whatever instance of B you end up creating.

Comment: class C looks like an inner class inside class B. Is that intentional or are you missing a closing brace? Can you please reformat your code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Extensions are semantic "is a" relations. Don't advice for extensions for accessibility reasons only, derivation is a pain in the ass in most cases and should be used only where it is semantically correct!

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Probably this is just a simplified example, and `B` does other things which weren't relevant to the question so they weren't included.